# Caching auth token in Node JS

Tags: node.js, caching, server, authorization

I am currently working on a project where there are multiple API calls being made from the server. Before each API service request is made (for instance CRUD just to make it simple), a token has to be sent with it as well since the paths are protected. This token is received by making an API call to a particular endpoint.

Now each time the service requests are made, an auth token request is also made to fetch the token. I want to know if it would be a good idea to cache the token instead of getting a new one on each service API call.
If so, what would be the best practices to implement this ? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the applications uses localStorage for storing auth tokens.